# Display images inside append

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have the following code :

```
$('.posts').append('<article class="post">\n' +
'                <div class="postImages">'+displayPostImagesHere()+'</div>\n' +
'            </article>');
```

and want to get images from firebase storage and display for each image in place of displayPostImagesHere() function the following code :

```
<div class="postImage"><img src="'+url+'" alt="Post image"></div>
```

Comment: Well your class id is missing an `s` or shouldn't have one. Cant say this will solve your problems but you also didn't include the db code did you?

Comment: No i didn't miss an s postImages have a lot of postImage, yes I did include the db code but I didn't find a way to insert with every post their images